# supervised tag suggestion for documents

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

I have thousands of documents with associated tag information. However i also have many documents without tags.

I want to train a model on the documents WITH tags and then apply the trained classifier to the UNTAGGED documents; the classifier will then suggest the most appropriate tags for each UNTAGGED document.

I have done quite a lot of research and there doesn't seem to be a SUPERVISED implementation to document tag classification.

I know NLTK, gensim, word2vec and other libraries will be useful for this problem.

I will be coding the project in Python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Supervised document tagging isn't particularly uncommon, though it's usually called "multiclass labelling". For many methods it's the same as single labelling but you pick the N-best results. See here for a scikit example on made-up data: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual use-case you might opt for more complex method but for minimum working model do:

1) Prepocessing of documents: tokenize, build vocabulary (NLTK has tools for this)

2) Do [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model#Application) encoding per document

3) Train a machine learning model with onehot encoding for outputs. Start from sklearn random forest, logistic regression, SVM.

Comment: thanks, i have  a minimum working model; bow representation of document text with an SVM learning model. Any advice on taking it further? more pre-processing (stemming ect...). I was thinking of using WMD to cluster tagged documents, then apply the model to untagged documents that would then find the most similar kind of tag documents, therefore giving you your tag.

Comment: From here it will begin to depend on your actual use case. But basically my answer is in three parts. 1) preprocessing 2) encoding 3) training model. Depending on your actual use-case and data the prioritization will differ. E.g. if you have 100mln documents but at test time don't need to worry about computation work with neural networks to get model better. If you have little data you might want to look into better preprocessing / encoding much more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on something similar,
besides what @Joonatan Samuel suggested I would encourage you to do careful preprocessing and considerations.

1. If you want two or more tags for documents you could train several model : one model per tag. You need to consider if there will be enough cases for each model (tag)
2. If you have a lot of tags, you could run into a problem with document-tag cases like above.
3. Stick to most common tag prediction don't try to predict all tags.